# Using glob() to display images, but images won't display

Tags: php

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to display all images from a server directory. I've tried implementing glob() to do this, and it appears to be nearly working, but for some reason the images don't appear. I'm using xampp to serve the page, and it's had no issues prior. I'm not sure what the problem could be. Below is the relevant code.

```
$size = 5;
$images = glob("../../ass1_data_stage2/jpg/*.JPG", GLOB_BRACE);
$width = (600 / $size);  

echo "<table><tr>"; 
for($i=1; $i < count($images); $i++) {
    if (($i % $size) == 0 and $i != 0) {
        echo "</tr><tr>"; 
    }

    $file = $images[$i]; 
    echo '<td><img src=$file width=$width."px" height="100px" alt="Random image" />   </td>'; 
}
echo "</tr>"; 

echo "</table>";
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Nice benchmark about getting files: http://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/

Comment: inspect your page source, what does your `img src` look like?

Comment: Your HTML is broken. `<img>` width/height attributes are NOT defined css style. it's `width=800 height=600`, not `width=800px height=600px`. As well, you've probably got incorrect paths on the `src` attribute, since you're globbing in a completely different directory from where your script is executing.

Comment: click on image and copy link of image , to see difference with what you expect

Comment: Remember to keep this in mind: This `*.JPG` is not the same as `*.jpg` in most cases.

Comment: @FaceOfJock Yeah, it's a common mistake. Just not certain if that alone will fix the OP's problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know , i think this is his problem or with the path ,he forgot probably to add a slash ,something like that

Comment: @FaceOfJock Most probable. And this `<img src=$file` is wrong, it should start as `<img src='$file` and I do believe `Matthew R` covered that aspect in his answer below.

Comment: The first rule of debugging your PHP code with a page that doesn't look correct is to look at the HTML that the PHP generates.  You have PHP code that generates HTML code that gets rendered in the browser.  You're asking us to go from PHP code and ignore the HTML code and go only off of what's rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is your exact issue, but your HTML syntax is incorrect for the image element:

```
echo '<td><img src=$file width=$width."px" height="100px" alt="Random image" /></td>';
```

Should be:

```
echo '<td><img src="'.$file.'" width="'.$width.'" height="100" alt="Random image" /></td>';
```

You could also use this method which is cleaner:

```
echo "<td><img src='{$file}' width='{$width}' height='100' alt='Random image' /></td>';
```

Comment: That and most probably the OP's call to `*.JPG` which is not the same as `*.jpg`. If all files (including extension) in OP's folder are in lowercase, then in most cases as on a Linux box, will fail if kept in uppercase.

Comment: Right, PHP doesn't replace variables inner single quoted strings, just in double quoted ones. P.S.: Single quoted strings are faster processed than double ones due to this reason.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, it was my syntax that was causing issues. All seems to be working normally now. And just to clarify with the .JPG. For some reason, the supplied images we were given are in .JPG and not .jpg. I know because that tripped me up before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example i used in one of my projects :

I suggest to use glob like this :

```
    $images = glob($path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG}', GLOB_BRACE);//only images
```

Example :

```
<?php

    $folder='name of your folder ';

    $path = 'uploads/'.$folder.'/' ;// slash in the end of path
    $images = glob($path . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,JPG}', GLOB_BRACE);//only images
    foreach ($images as $image) {
         echo "<img src='$image' />";
    }
?>
```